# 100% line coverage with static method

Tags: java, junit

I have the following class:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;

    public class TimeUtil {

        public static Timestamp getTimestamp() {
            java.util.Date currentTime = new java.util.Date();
            return new Timestamp(currentTime.getTime());
        }
    }
```

and coded following Junit class:

```
public class TimeUtilTest {

    @Test
    public void getTimestamp() {
        java.util.Date expected = new java.util.Date();
        Timestamp s = TimeUtil.getTimestamp();

        assertTrue("not in the expected 
        timeinterval",Math.abs(expected.getTime() - s.getTime()) < 20L);



}
```

}

---

My aim is to achieve 100% line coverage with that test, but currently only 66% lines are covered. Does anybody have an idea how I could maximize the line coverage?

Comment: Perhaps you do not test the *implicit* constructor?

Comment: think coverage 66% due to code coverage utils expect call of TimeUtil  constructor too . just call new TimeUtil ()

Comment: Just a general comment: 100% line coverage does not mean your code is properly tested and should in my opinion never be THE goal.

Comment: And your code can also fail if the time is updated between construction of the first and second `Date` object.

Comment: Just added "TimeUtil test = new TimeUtil(); " and it worked. Thanks to all!!!

Comment: @auenal would be better to create a private constructor to prevent an instance being created at all. Not sure how your coverage tools would respond to that, but that's the way you should code a class with only static methods.